# jq: error (at jsontest:1): Cannot index string with string

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

Im using linux and i need to get the data using jq from the following json, but i cannot :(

```
{"xJSON":"{\"statusCode\":\"200\", \"status\": \"OK\",\"pJSON\": \"{\"body\": {\"assets\": {\"loadingBackgroundImageBase64\": \"iVBII=\",\"loginBackgroundImageBase64\": \"iVBORwTkSuQmCC\",\"splashImageBase64\": \"iVBORw0KGgAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\",\"iconImageBase64\": \"iVBORw0KGgoAAAA6ZH+gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\"},\"build-configuration\": {\"token\": \"dwqsdadsa\",\"storePassword\": \"3332sa\",\"googleServicesAndroidBase64\": \"ewogICIxIgp9\",\"keystore\": \"/u3+7Iy4IJYPYxbg==\",\"keystore-password\": \"33332d\",\"keystore-alias\": \"consist\",\"googleServicesIOSBase64\": \"PD94bWc3Q+\"},\"appConfiguration\": {\"id\": \"94c2c3063ee3fbc3847ce6\",\"appVersion\": \"7.9.0\",\"buildVersion\": \"1.0.0.0.0\",\"responseContext\": \"pruebareportes\",\"soVersion\": \"android\",\"initialContext\": {\"name\": \"pruebareportes\",\"url\": \"pruebareportes.test.com\"},\"appName\": \"test\",\"appId\": \"com.rrrr.test\",\"tabs\": [{\"iconName\": \"icon_app-home\",\"configuration\": {\"item1\": \"prueba\"},\"title\": \"Inicio\",\"type\": \"home\"}]}}}\"}"}
```

I cannot get any data from it using jq, i keep getting nulls or "Cannot index string with string "

```
jq '.xJSON.statusCode' jsontest
jq: error (at jsontest:1): Cannot index string with string "statusCode"
...

jq '.appConfiguration.appId' jsontest
null
...
```

I Would really need some help, thanks!

Comment: The `xJSON` property is a nested JSON string, not an object. Use the `fromJSON` operator to parse it, as explained in the linked question.

Comment: `fromjson`, that is.